# Swizzling - Undo method selector swizzling in Objective-C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, selector, swizzling

We're making use of Swizzling in Objective-C. For convenience we're using CoconutKit's helper methods to achieve this:

```
HLSSwizzleSelectorWithBlock_Begin([TMObjectCache class], @selector(objectForKey:))
    ^(TMObjectCache *self, NSString *key) {
        key = nil;
        return ((id (*)(id, SEL, NSString*))_imp)(self, _cmd, key);

    }
HLSSwizzleSelectorWithBlock_End;
```

We'd like to however also un-swizzle this method after some point in the code. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CoconutKit, but swizzling is just a call to `method_exchangeImplementations()`. That function swaps two implementations. So if you call it again with the same parameters, you'll swap the implementations back. You'll need to look at how `HLSSwizzleSelectorWithBlock_Begin` builds up its call to `method_exchangeImplementations()` and make it again.

And of course, insert all standard warnings that swizzling is incredibly dangerous, fragile, primarily useful for debugging, and should be strongly avoided in production code if there is any other solution possible.

Comment: "swizzling is incredibly dangerous, fragile, primarily useful for debugging, and should be strongly avoided in production code" Except that Cocoa wlll happily do it to you behind your back. :(

Comment: Yeah; but the folks who did KVO had access to the source code, and all the Apple devs know not to break KVO. They don't have the same worry about your swizzles. (Of course KVO is isa-swizzling, not method-swizzling. Do you know an Apple-applied method-swizzle that I'm forgetting?)

Comment: I think KVO was the main one I had in mind; as you say, it isn't method swizzling, but I still regard it with suspicion (though I am compelled to use it).

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Swizzling does not *necessarily* use `method_exchangeImplementations`. In fact, it's better when it *doesn't*. https://blog.newrelic.com/2014/04/16/right-way-to-swizzle/